# Vue3 Typescript, failed to import component: "Component is not a module"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm unable to correctly import a component and I can't figure out why. When trying, i get the error "Component is not a module".

My child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="pagination">
    <span>
      <h3>Pagination</h3>
      <p>Previous</p>
      <p>Next</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts"></script>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

My parent:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/">Photos</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/posts">Posts</router-link>
    <Pagination />
  </nav>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Pagination from "@/components/PaginationComponent.vue";
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `setup` keyword in the Pagination component. Once you add it I believe it should be ok.